# ungetc in Python

Tags: python, readline, readlines, ungetc

Some file read (readlines()) functions in Python
copy the file contents to memory (as a list)

I need to process a file that's too large to
be copied in memory and as such need to use
a file pointer (to access the file one byte
at a time) -- as in C getc().

The additional requirement I have is that
I'd like to rewind the file pointer to previous
bytes like in C ungetc().

Is there a way to do this in Python?

Also, in Python, I can read one line at a
time with readline()

Is there a way to read the previous line
going backward?

Comment: worst / poem / ever. :)

Comment: What about ungetch from the msvcrt module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do want to use a file pointer directly (I think Mike Graham's suggestion is better though), you can use the file object's [seek()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) method which lets you set the internal pointer, combined with the [read()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) method, which support an option argument specifying how many bytes you'd like to read.

Answer (score 5):

- You do not need file pointers, which Python does not have or want.
- To go through a file line by line without reading the whole thing into memory, just iterate over the file object itself, i.e.

  ```
   with open(filename, "r") as f:
       for line in f:
           ...
  ```

  Using `readlines` is generally to be avoided.
- Going back a line isn't something you can do super-easily. If you never need to go back more than one line, check out the `pairwise` recipe in the [`itertools` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html).

Comment: How does pairwise compare in speed with seek()?

Comment: @Dragos, I could only guess, and I wouldn't even want to bother guessing. To know, I would time. And I would only time if I had code that was not running fast enough and I *knew* that this was the part of my code running too slow. **Bottlenecks occur at unexpected places**, so it is essential to use evidence when optimizing. http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html can give you some tools that will help you find out where your code is spending its time. With that info, consider if you can improve your algorithm or try timing various options with http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html

Answer (score 3):

OK, here's what I came up with.  Thanks Brenda for the idea of building a class.
Thanks Josh for the idea to use C like functions seek() and read()

```
#!/bin/python

# Usage: BufRead.py inputfile

import sys, os, string
from inspect import currentframe

# Debug function usage
#
# if DEBUG:
#   debugLogMsg(currentframe().f_lineno,currentframe().f_code.co_filename)
#   print ...
def debugLogMsg(line,file,msg=""):
  print "%s:%s %s" % (file,line,msg)

# Set DEBUG off.
DEBUG = 0

class BufRead: 
  def __init__(self,filename): 
    self.__filename           = filename 
    self.__file               = open(self.__filename,'rb') 
    self.__fileposition       = self.__file.tell()
    self.__file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    self.__filesize           = self.__file.tell() 
    self.__file.seek(self.__fileposition, os.SEEK_SET) 

  def close(self): 
    if self.__file is not None: 
      self.__file.close() 
      self.__file = None 

  def seekstart(self):
    if self.__file == None:
      self.__file.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
      self.__fileposition = self.__file.tell()

  def seekend(self):
    if self.__file == None:
      self.__file.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
      self.__fileposition = self.__file.tell()

  def getc(self):
    if self.__file == None:
      return None 
    self.__fileposition = self.__file.tell()
    if self.__fileposition < self.__filesize:
      byte = self.__file.read(1)
      self.__fileposition = self.__file.tell()
      return byte
    else:
      return None

  def ungetc(self):
    if self.__file == None:
      return None 
    self.__fileposition = self.__file.tell()
    if self.__fileposition > 0:
      self.__fileposition = self.__fileposition - 1
      self.__file.seek(self.__fileposition, os.SEEK_SET)
      byte = self.__file.read(1)
      self.__file.seek(self.__fileposition, os.SEEK_SET)
      return byte
    else:
      return None

  # uses getc() and ungetc()
  def getline(self):
    if self.__file == None:
      return None 
    self.__fileposition = self.__file.tell()

    if self.__fileposition < self.__filesize:
      startOfLine = False
      line = ""

      while True:
        if self.__fileposition == 0:
          startOfLine = True
          break
        else:
          c = self.ungetc()
          if c == '\n':
            c = self.getc()
            startOfLine = True
            break

      if startOfLine:
        c = self.getc()
        if c == '\n':
          return '\n'
        else:
          self.ungetc()

        while True:
          c = self.getc()
          if c == '\n':
            line += c
            c = self.getc()
            if c == None:
              return line
            if c == '\n':
              self.ungetc()
            return line
          elif c == None:
            return line
          else:
            line += c
    else:
      return None

  # uses getc() and ungetc()
  def ungetline(self):
    if self.__file == None:
      return None 
    self.__fileposition = self.__file.tell()

    if self.__fileposition > 0:
      endOfLine = False
      line = ""

      while True:
        if self.__fileposition == self.__filesize:
          endOfLine = True
          break
        else:
          c = self.getc()
          if c == '\n':
            c = self.ungetc()
            endOfLine = True
            break

      if endOfLine:
        c = self.ungetc()
        if c == '\n':
          return '\n'
        else:
          self.getc()

        while True:
          c = self.ungetc()
          if c == None:
            return line
          if c == '\n':
            line += c
            c = self.ungetc()
            if c == None:
              return line
            if c == '\n':
              self.getc()
            return line
          elif c == None:
            return line
          else:
            line = c + line
    else:
      return None

def main():
  if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    print sys.argv[1]
    b = BufRead(sys.argv[1])

    sys.stdout.write(
      '----------------------------------\n' \
      '- TESTING GETC                    \n' \
      '----------------------------------\n')

    while True:
      c = b.getc()
      if c == None: 
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
        break
      else:
        sys.stdout.write(c)

    sys.stdout.write(
      '----------------------------------\n' \
      '- TESTING UNGETC                  \n' \
      '----------------------------------\n')

    while True:
      c = b.ungetc()
      if c == None: 
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
        break
      else:
        sys.stdout.write(c)

    sys.stdout.write(
      '----------------------------------\n' \
      '- TESTING GETLINE                 \n' \
      '----------------------------------\n')

    b.seekstart()

    while True:
      line = b.getline()
      if line == None:
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
        break
      else:
        sys.stdout.write(line)

    sys.stdout.write(
      '----------------------------------\n' \
      '- TESTING UNGETLINE               \n' \
      '----------------------------------\n')

    b.seekend()

    while True:
      line = b.ungetline()
      if line == None:
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
        break
      else:
        sys.stdout.write(line)

    b.close()

if __name__=="__main__": main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a class the reads and buffers input for you, and implement ungetc on it -- something like this perhaps (warning: untested, written while compiling):

```
class BufRead:
    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.fn = open(filename,'rb')
        self.buffer = []
        self.bufsize = 256
        self.ready = True
    def close(self):
        if self.fn is not None:
            self.fn.close()
            self.fn = None
        self.ready = False
    def read(self,size=1):
        l = len(self.buffer)
        if not self.ready: return None
        if l <= size:
            s = self.buffer[:size]
            self.buffer = self.buffer[size:]
            return s
        s = self.buffer
        size = size - l
        self.buffer = self.fn.read(min(self.bufsize,size))
        if self.buffer is None or len(self.buffer) == 0:
            self.ready = False
            return s
        return s + self.read(size)
    def ungetc(self,ch):
        if self.buffer is None:
            self.buffer = [ch]
        else:   
            self.buffer.append(ch)
        self.ready = True
```

Comment: I'm in the process of building a class to do buffered reads of a file
via seek().

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to do billions of unbuffered single char file reads plus I wanted a way
to debug the position of the file pointer. Hence, I resolved to return the file position
in addition to a char or line and to use mmap to map the file to memory. (and let mmap
handle paging)  I think this will be a bit of a problem if the file is really, really big.
(as in larger than the amount of physical memory)  That's when mmap would start going into
the virtual memory and things could get really slow.  For now, it processes a 50 MB file   in about 4 min.

```
import sys, os, string, re, time
from mmap import mmap

class StreamReaderDb: 
  def __init__(self,stream):
    self.__stream             = mmap(stream.fileno(), os.path.getsize(stream.name))  
    self.__streamPosition     = self.__stream.tell()
    self.__stream.seek(0                    , os.SEEK_END)
    self.__streamSize         = self.__stream.tell() 
    self.__stream.seek(self.__streamPosition, os.SEEK_SET) 

  def setStreamPositionDb(self,streamPosition):
    if self.__stream == None:
      return None 
    self.__streamPosition = streamPosition
    self.__stream.seek(self.__streamPosition, os.SEEK_SET)

  def streamPositionDb(self):
    if self.__stream == None:
      return None 
    return self.__streamPosition

  def streamSize(self):
    if self.__stream == None:
      return None 
    return self.__streamSize

  def close(self): 
    if self.__stream is not None: 
      self.__stream.close() 
      self.__stream = None 

  def seekStart(self):
    if self.__stream == None:
      return None 
    self.setStreamPositionDb(0)

  def seekEnd(self):
    if self.__stream == None:
      return None 
    self.__stream.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
    self.setStreamPositionDb(self.__stream.tell())

  def getcDb(self):
    if self.__stream == None:
      return None,None 
    self.setStreamPositionDb(self.__stream.tell())
    if self.streamPositionDb() < self.streamSize():
      byte = self.__stream.read(1)
      self.setStreamPositionDb(self.__stream.tell())
      return byte,self.streamPositionDb()
    else:
      return None,self.streamPositionDb()

  def unGetcDb(self):
    if self.__stream == None:
      return None,None 
    self.setStreamPositionDb(self.__stream.tell())
    if self.streamPositionDb() > 0:
      self.setStreamPositionDb(self.streamPositionDb() - 1)
      byte = self.__stream.read(1)
      self.__stream.seek(self.streamPositionDb(), os.SEEK_SET)
      return byte,self.streamPositionDb()
    else:
      return None,self.streamPositionDb()

  def seekLineStartDb(self):
    if self.__stream == None:
      return None
    self.setStreamPositionDb(self.__stream.tell())

    if self.streamPositionDb() < self.streamSize():
      # Back up to the start of the line
      while True:
        if self.streamPositionDb() == 0:
          return self.streamPositionDb() 
        else:
          c,fp = self.unGetcDb()
          if c == '\n':
            c,fp = self.getcDb()
            return fp
    else:
      return None

  def seekPrevLineEndDb(self):
    if self.__stream == None:
      return None
    self.setStreamPositionDb(self.__stream.tell())

    if self.streamPositionDb() < self.streamSize():
      # Back up to the start of the line
      while True:
        if self.streamPositionDb() == 0:
          return self.streamPositionDb() 
        else:
          c,fp = self.unGetcDb()
          if c == '\n':
            return fp
    else:
      return None

  def seekPrevLineStartDb(self):
    if self.__stream == None:
      return None
    self.setStreamPositionDb(self.__stream.tell())

    if self.streamPositionDb() < self.streamSize():
      # Back up to the start of the line
      while True:
        if self.streamPositionDb() == 0:
          return self.streamPositionDb() 
        else:
          c,fp = self.unGetcDb()
          if c == '\n':
            return self.seekLineStartDb()
    else:
      return None

  def seekLineEndDb(self):
    if self.__stream == None:
      return None 
    self.setStreamPositionDb(self.__stream.tell())

    if self.streamPositionDb() > 0:
      while True:
        if self.streamPositionDb() == self.streamSize():
          return self.streamPositionDb()
        else:
          c,fp = self.getcDb()
          if c == '\n':
            c,fp = self.unGetcDb()
            return fp
    else:
      return None

  def seekNextLineEndDb(self):
    if self.__stream == None:
      return None 
    self.setStreamPositionDb(self.__stream.tell())

    if self.streamPositionDb() > 0:
      while True:
        if self.streamPositionDb() == self.streamSize():
          return self.streamPositionDb()
        else:
          c,fp = self.getcDb()
          if c == '\n':
            return fp
    else:
      return None

  def seekNextLineStartDb(self):
    if self.__stream == None:
      return None 
    self.setStreamPositionDb(self.__stream.tell())

    if self.streamPositionDb() > 0:
      while True:
        if self.streamPositionDb() == self.streamSize():
          return self.streamPositionDb()
        else:
          c,fp = self.getcDb()
          if c == '\n':
            return self.seekLineStartDb()
    else:
      return None

  # uses getc() and ungetc()
  def getLineDb(self):
    if self.__stream == None:
      return None,None 
    self.setStreamPositionDb(self.__stream.tell())

    line = ""

    if self.seekLineStartDb() != None:
      c,fp = self.getcDb()
      if c == '\n':
        return c,self.streamPositionDb()
      else:
        self.unGetcDb()

      while True:
        c,fp = self.getcDb()
        if c == '\n':
          line += c
          c,fp = self.getcDb()
          if c == None:
            return line,self.streamPositionDb()
          self.unGetcDb()
          return line,self.streamPositionDb()
        elif c == None:
          return line,self.streamPositionDb()
        else:
          line += c
    else:
      return None,self.streamPositionDb()

  # uses getc() and ungetc()
  def unGetLineDb(self):
    if self.__stream == None:
      return None,None 
    self.setStreamPositionDb(self.__stream.tell())

    line = ""

    if self.seekLineEndDb() != None:
      c,fp = self.unGetcDb()
      if c == '\n':
        return c,self.streamPositionDb()
      else:
        self.getcDb()

      while True:
        c,fp = self.unGetcDb()
        if c == None:
          return line,self.streamPositionDb()
        if c == '\n':
          line += c
          c,fp = self.unGetcDb()
          if c == None:
            return line,self.streamPositionDb()
          self.getcDb()
          return line,self.streamPositionDb()
        elif c == None:
          return line,self.streamPositionDb()
        else:
          line = c + line
    else:
      return None,self.streamPositionDb()
```

Answer (score 0):

The question was initially prompted by my need to build a lexical analyzer.
getc() and ungetc() are useful at first (to get the read bugs out the way and
to build the state machine)  After the state machine is done,
getc() and ungetc() become a liability as they take too long to read
directly from storage.

When the state machine was complete (debugged any IO problems,
finalized the states), I optimized the lexical analyzer.

Reading the source file in chunks (or pages) into memory and running
the state machine on each page yields the best time result.

I found that considerable time is saved if getc() and ungetc() are not used
to read from the file directly.

Comment: Seems odd to me since pythons open/read are buffered IO, so you're reading from memory anyway.   Unless you're using `os.open`